# Group By on a complex array

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

I've got an array like this:

```
scripts
    [
      ["scriptNameA", "dateAsString1", number],
      ["scriptNameB", "dateAsString1", number],
      ["scriptNameC", "dateAsString2", number],
      ["scriptNameD", "dateAsString3", number],
      ["scriptNameE", "dateAsString3", number]
    ]
```

and I'd like to get an array grouped by the date like

```
scriptsGroupedByDate[
    "dateAsString1"[
        ["scriptNameA", "dateAsString1", number],
        ["scriptNameB", "dateAsString1", number]
    ],
    "dateAsString2"[
        ["scriptNameC", "dateAsString2", number]
    ],
    "dateAsString3"[
        ["scriptNameD", "dateAsString3", number],
        ["scriptNameE", "dateAsString3", number]
    ]
]
```

is there a way to do this ?
thank you

Comment: Please add a valid output. Do you want a 2D array? Or an object with `dateAsString1` etc as key and grouped arrays as value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let number = 0;

let scripts =
    [
        ["scriptNameA", "dateAsString1", number],
        ["scriptNameB", "dateAsString1", number],
        ["scriptNameC", "dateAsString2", number],
        ["scriptNameD", "dateAsString3", number],
        ["scriptNameE", "dateAsString3", number]
    ];

var result = scripts.reduce((a, b) => (a[b[1]] ? a[b[1]].push(b) : a[b[1]] = [b], a), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well and helped me a lot  !!

Comment: please keep in mind that answers here are not necessarily the best.  I'm guilty of this myself.  I try to come up with a small snippet of code that works because it's sometimes a race to see who can answer first.  End the end, it works, but it's not very readable.  Anyway, your're welcome but rewrite it so it's readable.  Some answers though are very detailed and well thought out and I congraduate those that take the time and do it right

Answer (score 1):

It's easy using reduce

```js
let number = 0;
let scripts = [
  ['scriptNameA', 'dateAsString1', number],
  ['scriptNameB', 'dateAsString1', number],
  ['scriptNameC', 'dateAsString2', number],
  ['scriptNameD', 'dateAsString3', number],
  ['scriptNameE', 'dateAsString3', number]
];

const res = scripts.reduce((a, b) => a.set(b[1], (a.get(b[1]) || []).concat(b)),new Map);
console.log(res) // open the console, SO's console output can't Map;
```

You can easily transform the resulting Map to whatever structure you prefer then..

Answer (score 0):

@gkelly and others: Tnx for those great answers. I had a while to grasp all that syntax. Here is the same answer, so you can debug through it step by step and see how it works. Sorry to post it as an answer, but I do not know how to format code in comments.

```
let number = 0;
let scripts =
    [
        ["scriptNameA", "dateAsString1", number],
        ["scriptNameB", "dateAsString1", number],
        ["scriptNameC", "dateAsString2", number],
        ["scriptNameD", "dateAsString3", number],
        ["scriptNameE", "dateAsString3", number]
    ];


var func = function(accum, arrayitem) {
    debugger;

    //arrayitem is one of the five items in the scripts array. It is itself an array.
    //The 2nd item (zero based index) is the groupby value
    var groupByVal = arrayitem[1];

    //the accumulator is first an empty object (second parameter to reduce function)
    if(accum[groupByVal]){
        accum[groupByVal].push(arrayitem);
    }
    else {
        accum[groupByVal] = [arrayitem];
    }
    return accum;
};

var result = scripts.reduce(func, {});
console.log(result);
```